# Не понимаю, в чем ошибки программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

При нажатии на кнопку `Window2` просто выводит пустое окно `Toplevel` и множество ошибок. Должно выводить по крайней мере `Listbox`ы.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pickle

class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
        self.but_student = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Student", width=15, command=self.student_window)
        self.window3 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Window 2", font="Serene 10", fg='white', bg='black', command=self.window3).place(x=100, y=340)
        self.window4 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Window 3", fg='white', bg='black', font="Serene 10").place(x=250, y=340)
        self.window5 = tk.Button(self.frame, fg='white', bg='black', text="Window 4", font="Serene 10").place(x=400, y=340)
        self.but_student.place(x=386, y=0)
        self.frame.pack()

    A = set()
    B = set()

    def student_window(self):
        self.this_student = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app = Window2(self.this_student)

    def window3(self):
        self.window_3 = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app2 = Window3(self.window_3)


class Window2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
        self.info_student = tk.Label(self.frame, text='Артем\n'
                                                      'група\n'
                                                      'номер у списку 19\n'
                                                      'варіант {}'.format(self.variant(71, 19)), font="Arial 17 bold").pack(fill='both')
        self.frame.pack()

    def variant(self, g, n):
        return (n + g % 60) % 30 + 1


class Window3:
    global A, B

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()
        tk.Label(self.frame, text='Задайте множини А та В', font='Serene 16 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        var = tk.IntVar()
        self.variable = var.set(0)
        rad0 = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Множина A", font='Serene 12 bold', variable=var, value=0)
        rad1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Множина B", font='Serene 12 bold', variable=var, value=1)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=1)
        rad1.grid(column=0, row=2)

        lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Жіночі імена", font='Serene 12')
        lf1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.women = ['Настя', 'Маша', 'Аня', 'Катя', 'Юля', 'Даша', 'Оля', 'Люда']
        listbox1 = tk.Listbox(lf1, font='Serene 14')
        for i in self.women:
            listbox1.insert(i)
        listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.add_women)
        listbox1.grid(row=3, column=0)

        scr1 = tk.Scrollbar(lf1, command=listbox1.yview)
        listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=scr1.set)
        scr1.grid(row=3, column=1, ipady=90)

        lf2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Чоловічі імена", font='Serene 12')
        lf2.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2)

        self.men = ['Андрій', 'Антон', 'Денис', 'Богдан', 'Віталій', 'Віктор', 'Костя', 'Сергій', 'Вова']
        listbox2 = tk.Listbox(lf2, font='Arial 14')
        for i in self.men:
            listbox2.insert(END, i)
        listbox2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.add_men)
        listbox2.grid(row=3, column=2)

        scr2 = tk.Scrollbar(lf2, command=listbox2.yview)
        listbox2.configure(yscrollcommand=scr2.set)
        scr2.grid(row=3, column=3, ipady=90)

        tk.Button(self.frame, text='Очистити множини', font='Arial 12', command=self.clean_lists)\
            .grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.but = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Зберегти в файл', font='Arial 12', command=self.save_to_file)
        self.but.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2)

        tk.Button(self.frame, text='Показати з файлу', font='Arial 12', command=self.show_from_file)\
            .grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

        lf3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Задані множини', font='Arial 12', )
        lf3.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5)
        self.lb = tk.Label(lf3, text='A = {}\n'
                             'B = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B), font='Arial 14')
        self.lb.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5)
        A = self.A
        B = self.B

    def add_women(self, event):
            if self.variable.get() == 0:
                self.A.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            if self.variable.get() == 1:
                self.B.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            self.lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

    def add_men(self, event):
            if self.variable.get() == 0:
                self.A.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            if self.variable.get() == 1:
                self.B.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            self.lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

    def clean_lists(self):
        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()
        self.lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

    def save_to_file(self):
        self.f = open('МножиниАВ.txt', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.A, self.f)
        pickle.dump(self.B, self.f)
        self.f.close()
        self.but['text'] = 'Збережено'
        self.but['state'] = DISABLED

    def show_from_file(self):
        self.show = tk.Toplevel(self.frame)
        self.show.title('Window2/Show_sets')
        self.show.focus_set()
        self.show.minsize(300, 100)
        self.f = open('МножиниАВ.txt', 'rb')
        tk.Label(self.show, text='A={}\n'
                                 'B={}'.format(pickle.load(self.f), pickle.load(self.f)), font='Arial 14', justify=LEFT).pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.f.close()

#class Window4(tk.Frame):

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А ошибки вы сами угадайте, у меня лапки

Comment: Старайтесь более информативные заголовки использовать, более специфичные именно для вашей проблемы (*"не понимаю, в чем ошибки программы"* -- чересчур расплывчато)
 [ask]¶ Вместо вываливания всего кода, который у вас есть, без разбора, создайте *минимальный* пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему, описав словами желаемое поведение и подробно по шагам что вместо этого происходит [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала у вас была ошибка в том что когда вы вставляете объект в `listbox`  у вас должно быть 2 значение т.е. значение в какое место вставлять объект и какой объект ( как было `listbox1.insert(i)` как стало `listbox1.insert(tk.END, i)`.
Потому вы не разместили ваш фрейм в `Toplevel` в конце

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
    ......
    self.frame.pack()
```

А исправленный класс выглядит примерно так

```
class Window3:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()
        tk.Label(self.frame, text='Задайте множини А та В', font='Serene 16 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        var = tk.IntVar()
        self.variable = var.set(0)
        rad0 = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Множина A", font='Serene 12 bold', variable=var, value=0)
        rad1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="Множина B", font='Serene 12 bold', variable=var, value=1)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=1)
        rad1.grid(column=0, row=2)

        lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Жіночі імена", font='Serene 12')
        lf1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.women = ['Настя', 'Маша', 'Аня', 'Катя', 'Юля', 'Даша', 'Оля', 'Люда']
        listbox1 = tk.Listbox(lf1, font='Serene 14')
        for i in self.women:
            print(i)
            listbox1.insert(tk.END, i)
        listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.add_women)
        listbox1.grid(row=3, column=0)

        scr1 = tk.Scrollbar(lf1, command=listbox1.yview)
        listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=scr1.set)
        scr1.grid(row=3, column=1, ipady=90)

        lf2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Чоловічі імена", font='Serene 12')
        lf2.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2)

        self.men = ['Андрій', 'Антон', 'Денис', 'Богдан', 'Віталій', 'Віктор', 'Костя', 'Сергій', 'Вова']
        listbox2 = tk.Listbox(lf2, font='Arial 14')
        for i in self.men:
            listbox2.insert(tk.END, i)
        listbox2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.add_men)
        listbox2.grid(row=3, column=2)

        scr2 = tk.Scrollbar(lf2, command=listbox2.yview)
        listbox2.configure(yscrollcommand=scr2.set)
        scr2.grid(row=3, column=3, ipady=90)

        tk.Button(self.frame, text='Очистити множини', font='Arial 12', command=self.clean_lists)\
            .grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.but = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Зберегти в файл', font='Arial 12', command=self.save_to_file)
        self.but.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2)

        tk.Button(self.frame, text='Показати з файлу', font='Arial 12', command=self.show_from_file)\
            .grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

        lf3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Задані множини', font='Arial 12', )
        lf3.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5)
        self.lb = tk.Label(lf3, text='A = {}\n'
                             'B = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B), font='Arial 14')
        self.lb.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5)
        A = self.A
        B = self.B
        self.frame.pack()
  .....
```